# how to set a path to save the file during runtime using python?

Tags: python, file, directory, filepath

I have created a new directories 'Student' and 'Faculty' using os.mkdir(). I need save the student files in 'Student' folder and employee details in the 'Faculty' folder. How do I do it manually? I need to set a path to write a file into the student and faculty folder.

```
import os
stuDir = 'StudentDetails'
os.mkdir(stuDir)
facDir = 'FacultyDetails'
os.mkdir(facDir)
if(tempNo[0]=='E'):
 #I need to set a path to 'Faculty'folder
elif(tempNo[0]=='R'):
 #I need to set a path to 'Student'folder
f=open(outfile, 'w')
for j in tempList2:
  if(temp==j[0]):
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerow(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the current directory to the directory you want using `os.chdir('complete_path_you_want_to_switch')` if else blocks and try writing the files there.

[os.chdir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir)

Comment: I have created those folders in current working directory.If this is the case,what 'complete_path_you_want_to_switch' refers to?

Comment: `complete_path_you_want_to_switch` refers to your `Student` folder or `Faculty` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.getcwd` to the current working directory

```
path=os.getcwd();
```

Then append directory,outfile to that path

```
f=open(path+stuDir+outfile, 'w')
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CollegeInfo.py", line 175, in <module>
    obj.writeCsv(sql,individualName)
  File "CollegeInfo.py", line 84, in writeCsv
    os.mkdir(stuDir)
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'Student'

Comment: the error says file or directory already exists, please make sure they are deleted and try executing again @SaravananSelvam

Answer (score 0):

Just use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` if you want a relative path, and use `os.path.join()` to join paths. To write the file in the folder you just created, simply use the same filepath, as in this example:

```
import os
stuDir = 'StudentDetails'
stuDir_filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), stuDir)
os.mkdir(stuDir_filepath)

facDir = 'FacultyDetails'
facDir_filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), facDir)
os.mkdir(facDir_filepath)

name_of_file = "name_file"
file_path= os.path.join(facDir_filepath, name_of_file+".txt")         
file1 = open(file_path, "w")
toFile = "Some Text here"
file1.write(toFile)
file1.close()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CollegeInfo.py", line 179, in <module>
    obj.writeCsv(sql,individualName)
  File "CollegeInfo.py", line 85, in writeCsv
    os.mkdir(stuDir_filepath)
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'Student'

Comment: This just means your folder/file 'Student' already exists :) if you delete it, it will work. My suggestion is that you verify if the folder exists before creating it with mkdir.

Comment: Yeah,I deleted the folder and tried again.But,still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you are deleting the right folder? This code works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.6+ there is a new Path object from [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) which can work like this for your situation.  In this example there is not a need to set a path.  stuDir and facDir are assumed to be local paths and they can give you the full path with .absolute() afterwards e.g. `facDir.absolute()`

```
from pathlib import Path
outfile = "somefilenamehere.csv"
stuDir = Path('StudentDetails')
facDir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

facDir = Path('FacultyDetails')
facDir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

if(tempNo[0]=='E'):
    #now outfile is a path
    outfile = facDir/outfile
elif(tempNo[0]=='R'):
    outfile = facDir/outfile
#try out this last line as I can't verify that it works without some data which was not provided.
outfile.write_lines([csv.writer(j) for j in tempList2 if temp==j[0]]
```